# Pentaho Compress File

Tags: pentaho

Is it possible to compress a file so that it is even smaller than the normal compression option? I need to compress files in the best way possible, but in pentaho when we are going to send the file by email it simply compresses... there is no option to compress even less

Send a file with the best compress

Comment: Very likely you can't. What makes you think that should be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a more potent compressor installed in your server/machine where you are executing PDI, you can use a shell script to perform the compression and execute that shell script using Pentaho.